# I need to solve FormatException: Unexpected character Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone I got this exception (Unexpected character ) when I call this json.decode(jsonString), but  some times when I run the app it doesn't throw any exception .
when this exception appear the expect data that comes from server doesn't displayed on the app .
**I test my API in localhost .**
my code :

```
Future<List<Governorate>> getGovernorates() async {
    var governorates = List<Governorate>();
    var governorate = await client.get('$endpoint/governorates');
    String jsonString = governorate.body?.toString();
    if(governorate.statusCode == 200){
      //print("governorate =====> ${jsonString}");
      var parsed= json.decode(jsonString) as List<dynamic>; // sometimes it's fails here and throw the exeption FormatException: Unexpected character 
      for(var gov in parsed){
        governorates.add(Governorate.fromJson(gov));
      }
    } else {
      throw "Can't get governorates";
    }
    return governorates;
  }
```

json object :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "governorate_name": "test governorate",
        "governorate_cities": []
    },
 {
        "id": 1,
        "governorate_name": "test governorate 2",
        "governorate_cities": [
                              {
                "id": 11,
                "city_name": "test city",
                "governorate_id": 1
               
            }

]
    }
]
```

I try to solve this problem but  I don't success I hope you guys give my the Idea about this problem and how can I solve it
Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your answer.

Comment: try to decode as Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: my returned response it's not subtype of Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: the jsonobject you showed us is the print from flutter? or it's the actual jsonObject, cause if it is, it shouldn't include trailing comma for values

Comment: cause maybe the root object is an array

Comment: assign the root object to some key and then try to parse it as a Map<String,Dynamic>

Comment: If you get a `FormatException` at that point, then it's because your `jsonString`  does not contain valid JSON text. Can you show an example of a text that *actually* gives the error, and check whether the `FormatException` tells you which character is wrong? (It might give you the precise position in the string which is wrong). Check that the string does not contain any extra characters, or some spaces are really 0xA0 (nbsp) characters.

(If you are running on the web, you might not get more information because the parsing happens in JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the code that I have implemented based on your json provided.

This is the json you provided.

```
[
    {
       "id":1,
       "governorate_name":"test governorate",
       "governorate_cities":[
 
       ]
    },
    {
       "id":1,
       "governorate_name":"test governorate 2",
       "governorate_cities":[
          {
             "id":11,
             "city_name":"test city",
             "governorate_id":1
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

And from the above json I have created a model class for it just check it out

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final governorate = governorateFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Governorate> governorateFromJson(String str) => List<Governorate>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Governorate.fromJson(x)));

String governorateToJson(List<Governorate> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Governorate {
    Governorate({
        this.id,
        this.governorateName,
        this.governorateCities,
    });

    int id;
    String governorateName;
    List<GovernorateCity> governorateCities;

    factory Governorate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Governorate(
        id: json["id"],
        governorateName: json["governorate_name"],
        governorateCities: List<GovernorateCity>.from(json["governorate_cities"].map((x) => GovernorateCity.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "governorate_name": governorateName,
        "governorate_cities": List<dynamic>.from(governorateCities.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class GovernorateCity {
    GovernorateCity({
        this.id,
        this.cityName,
        this.governorateId,
    });

    int id;
    String cityName;
    int governorateId;

    factory GovernorateCity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GovernorateCity(
        id: json["id"],
        cityName: json["city_name"],
        governorateId: json["governorate_id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "city_name": cityName,
        "governorate_id": governorateId,
    };
}
```

And this is where I have shown a sample ui in the listview for the name.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:json_parsing_example/models.dart';



void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Users'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  List<Governorate> dataList = List();
  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    final governorate = governorateFromJson(jsonString);

    dataList = governorate;

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
/* 

// This will be in your case as per you code  
  Future<List<Governorate>> getGovernorates() async {
    var governorates = List<Governorate>();
    var governorate = await client.get('$endpoint/governorates');
    String jsonString = governorate.body?.toString();
    if(governorate.statusCode == 200){
     
    return governorateFromJson(jsonString);
    }
  } */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: dataList.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return Card(
                        child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(dataList[i].governorateName),
                    ));
                  }),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

This might happen because the list is empty just check the following code and let  me know still the error occurs

Change the following factory method from the model class

```
factory NewMessagesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NewMessagesModel(
        id: json["id"],
        governorateName: json["governorate_name"],
        governorateCities: json["governorate_cities"] ==null ?null:List<GovernorateCity>.from(json["governorate_cities"].map((x) => GovernorateCity.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "governorate_name": governorateName,
        "governorate_cities":json["governorate_cities"] ==null?null : List<dynamic>.from(governorateCities.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}
```

just check the commented code where I have taken you api fetching code and made some modifications so that it would work and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks bro, but also sometimes works and sometime I got the same exception like before

Comment: just check the code at last that I have add two json the json you provided has some issues regarding the , character and if its removed the it might work fine just check with your api developer for the json standard

Comment: the extra comma I  forgot to delete when I copied a part of my json because it's a long json object .
sorry for that mistake I edit the post

Comment: Can you just add the complete log of the error that you are getting?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/axXOlB
but i'm wondering why sometimes works perfectly :|

Comment: Just check the code that I have added to the last and let me know if the error still there